# Angular Delete image from preview

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a file input, I can select several and see their preview ... How can I remove them from the preview if necessary?

**HTML**

```
 <img [src]="urls[0]">
      <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">


    <div class="row">
      <a class="folder_Up">
        <img src="assets/folderUP.svg" title="Item attachments" />       
      </a>

      <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls | slice:1">
          <img [src]="url">
      </div>

        <div class="Upcard">
          <div class="card-block">
          </div>
        </div>
```

**Angular(typescript)**

```
urls = new Array<string>();
  detectFiles(event) {
    this.urls = [];
    let files = event.target.files;
    if (files) {
      for (let file of files) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e: any) => {
          this.urls.push(e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
    }
  }
```

**what I tried but to no avail**

```
  <div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls | slice:1">
          <img [src]="url"><span class="delete-entry" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(image)">x</span>
      </div>

 private deleteImage(image: any): void {
    this.urls = this.urls.filter((a) => a !== image);
  }
```

Comment: Try `(click)="deleteImage(url)"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looping over the  urls and using `url` to display image, you should use the same for delete:

```
//  *ngFor="let url of urls

<div class="Upcard" *ngFor="let url of urls | slice:1">
          <img [src]="url"><span class="delete-entry" style="cursor: pointer;" (click)="deleteImage(url)">x</span>
      </div>
```

And in the component, remove url from list:

```
private deleteImage(url: any): void {
    this.urls = this.urls.filter((a) => a !== url);
}
```

Comment: This works in small boxes, in the big box I present the first selected image, how can I delete this?       `<img [src]="urls[0]">
      <input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)">`

Comment: you can get the `src` or the value of img from `$event` object and try using that. Try to log the $event and see what values does this object contain.

Comment: i'm having a bug using src = urls [0], it always tries to load an image even if it's empty -.-

Comment: You can use `?` to find out if url is available or create a method in component to return url[0] or use index for `*ngFor`: `<img *ngIf="i === 0"[src]="photo[i]?.url_cdn">`

Comment: I still can't get it to work. I will test your solution and then say something. Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: In fact, he no longer tries to upload an image even if it doesn't exist. But when I have add an image, that image does not appear in that box, ie this solution is not loading me the image

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I've used this exact way to remove preview pics from a website of mine)

Angular

```
$scope.removeItem = function (url) {
    $scope.urls.splice(url, 1);
};
```

HTML

```
<a ng-click="removeItem(url)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```